# Connect EF to SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ssms

I'm using EF code-first and I want it to create the new database in SQL Server Management Studio instance instead of using the integrated SQL Server in Visual Studio.

I added this to my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BillFo" 
         connectionString="Data Source=SELANL293;Initial Catalog=Billfo;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But it doesn't help. No nothing happens, nothing in the integrated SQL Server and nothing in my SQL Server Management Studio. How do I make it create my database in Management Studio rather then the SQL Server in Visual Studio?

Comment: SQL Management Studio is a program which you use to connect to an Instance of SQL Server (of any version) and view that server's contents.  You could use SQL Management Studio to connect to your `(localdb)` instance from Visual Studio, and you can run more than one version of SQL on a single machine.  So you likely need to figure out what SQL Server instance you are trying to connect to, and the full path to that instance.... the current `Data Source=` line in your example is not a full server path.

Comment: somehow it is kind of working with my connectionstring. I can't delete the database BillFo from management studio. When i try to delete it it says that it is in use so it can't be deleted.

Comment: What about this then:

 <add name="BillFo"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=SELANL293\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=BillFo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

Comment: that Data Source looks more complete...

Answer (score 0):

try add this section

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="connection string......"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="......" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

you do not have to use `<parameters>` property , you can use your currently connection string configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="YourEFContextName" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SqlServerInstanceName; Initial Catalog=DataBaseName; User ID=UserName; password=YourPassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The section `entityFramework` should be created automatically.