# Connection to SQL Server Management Studio with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, ssms

I'm using VS 2013 and EF 6 and I want EF to create a database in SQL Server Management Studio. I'm getting this error right now:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

With this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BillFo"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=SELANL293\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=BillFo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is my context class:

```
public class BillContext : DbContext
{
    static BillContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<BillContext>(null);
    }

    public BillContext()
        : base("Name=BillFo")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BillType> BillTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attachments> Attachments { get; set; } 
}
```

I just can't get it to work out.

//EDIT//

I tried this connection string:

```
<add name="BillFo"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=SELANL293;Initial Catalog=BillFo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

and got this error instead:

> Cannot open database \"BillFo\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'BESAM\dangus'.

Comment: SQL Server **Management Studio** is only a **GUI based management tool** - it's not a system where you in which you can *create* a database..... the database gets created inside **SQL Server** - not the Management Studio ...

Comment: Where do i do that? The database is not created so that i can do it in management studio.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348508/connect-ef-to-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot marc_s!!:)

Comment: Thank you for asking this question....I'm having exactly the same problem with EF6 and VS2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have EF create your database, you need to **specify** a valid initializer!

See this article [Database Initialization Strategies in code-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) for details - basically, you need to define what initializer should be run:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

static BillContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<BillContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BillContext>());
}
```

or something else - just passing `null` to the `.SetInitializer` call tells EF to *do nothing* --> no database is ever going to be created!

Comment: Thank you for answering this!  I knew I needed to be specifying that the database should be created somewhere, but MS's walkthrough on EF Code First completely neglected to mention this part.